# Is it possible to have a dynamic namePrefix/nameSuffix in kustomize?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kustomize

In Helm, it is possible to specify a release name using

`helm install my-release-name chart-path`

This means, I can specify the release name and its components (using fullname) using the CLI.

In kustomize (I am new to kustomize), there is a similar concept, [`namePrefix`](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/nameprefix/) and [`nameSuffix`](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/namesuffix/) which can be defined in a `kustomization.yaml`

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

namePrefix: overlook-

resources:
- deployment.yaml
```

However, this approach needs a custom file, and using a "dynamic" namePrefix would mean that a `kustomization.yaml` has to be generated using a template and kustomize is, well,  about avoiding templating.

Is there any way to specify that value dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`kustomize edit`](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/mySql/README.md#name-customization) to edit the `nameprefix` and `namesuffix` values.

For example:

`Deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: the-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 5
  template:
    containers:
      - name: the-container
        image: registry/conatiner:latest
```

`Kustomization.yaml`

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
- deployment.yaml
```

Then you can run `kustomize edit set nameprefix dev-` and `kustomize build .` will return following:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dev-the-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 5
  template:
    containers:
    - image: registry/conatiner:latest
      name: the-container
```

Comment: better then templating, however for CI it would be if it was't necessary to make changes to file, but accepting it since I guess there is no such option